# How can a return statement after a function call, output string with double quote to console?

Tags: javascript

How can a return statement after a function call, output string with double quote to console. I'm getting only single quotes.

```
 var BMI;
var message;
function bmiCalculator(weight, height)
    {
        BMI = Math.round((weight / (height * height))*100)/100;
       
     if (BMI < 18.5){
             message = "Your BMI is " + BMI + ", so your are underweight.";

        }

        if (BMI > 18.5 && BMI < 24.9){
          message =  "Your BMI is " + BMI + ", so your are normal.";
}
        if  (BMI > 24.9){
             message = "Your BMI is " + BMI + ", so your are overweight.";

        }
        return message;
    }
    

 bmiCalculator(90, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes in javascript to delimit strings, which means your double quotes become regular strings e.g.

```
console.log('Hello "world"').
```

Otherwise you are looking for the javascript string escape character which works like this:

```
console.log("Hello \"world\"").
```

Comment: Thanks but without using a console.log(). When i call the function, it should return a string with double quotes.

Comment: The concept applies to all strings, so `return 'Hello "world"'` ... or am I missing something here?